# Params hash is empty when POSTing JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parameters

I am using the "default" create method from the scaffold:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(firstname: params[:firstname], surname: params[:surname])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

(I know I'm not using strong parameters there, but whatever :)).

When I am sending a POST request using a very specific REST client, the params hash doesn't contain the parameters. When I look at the request.body, it contains the parameters as JSON. Also, content_type is "application/json

To fix this issue I had to had

```
   before_filter :fix_json_params
   [...]
   def fix_json_params
      if request.content_type == "application/json"
        @reparsed_params = JSON.parse(request.body.string).with_indifferent_access
      end
    end

    private

    def params
      @reparsed_params || super
    end
```

However, I don't understand why?? Why isn't rails parsing my json body correctly if content_type is correct? Any idea?

This is using rails '4.2.4'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your params_warrper.rb:

on the top of your controller put:

```
wrap_parameters format: [:json]
```

then it should automatic parse it as a JSON.

Comment: Hello, thank your for your help. The params hash is still empty :/.